# JSF/Facelets ajax view render issue

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, facelets

I have a .xhtml with two commandlink buttons and two outputpanels. Everything inside same form. When I click on commandlink why do I need to explicitly say which output panels need to be rendered? If nothing specified, shouldn't entire view re-constructed based on following description from Spec (or) Am I mixing things?

As well as do we really need to set `action="navigation-rule"` when we want to refresh a component in same view?

```
Link controls are typically used to perform complete form submissions for data storing.
As a consequence, the <a4j:commandLink> component has the execute="@form" setting by default.
```

Any input is much appreciated.

Here is code for reference:

```
 <h:form>
        <div>
            <a4j:outputPanel layout="block">
                <!--Tab1 -->
                <a4j:commandLink
                    id="homeTabLinkId"
                    value="Tab1"
                    actionListener="somelistener" render="contentDIVId">
                    <h:outputText value=""/>
                </a4j:commandLink>
                <!--Hosts Tab -->
                <a4j:commandLink 
                    id="hostsTabLinkId"
                    value="Tab2"
                    actionListener="anotherlistener" render="contentDIVId">
                    <h:outputText value=""/>
                </a4j:commandLink>


            </a4j:outputPanel>
        </div>

        <a4j:outputPanel layout="block" id="contentDIVId">
            <!-- dynamically gets src based on tab click -->
            <ui:include id="tabBodyPanel" src="elexpression"/>
        </a4j:outputPanel>

        <a4j:outputPanel layout="block" id="anotherdiv">
            <h:outputText value="Inside second div"/>
        </a4j:outputPanel>

    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If nothing specified, shouldn't entire view re-constructed based on following description from Spec (or) Am I mixing things?*

That applies only to synchronous requests. Replace `<a4j:commandLink>` by `<h:commandLink>` and you'll get the described behaviour.

---

> *As well as do we really need to set action="navigation-rule" when we want to refresh a component in same view?*

No. The action method can just return `null` or `void`. Otherwise the view will be recreated and that isn't what you want if you've view scoped beans on the view.

Comment: Hi BalusC: Some how a4j:commandlink has that description in the spec which confused me. Another, if we have request scoped beans, then do we need to specify action=navigation-rule-id in component?

Comment: No, a `null` or `void` outcome defaults to the current view. The difference with request scoped beans is that they're just recreated on every request.